# Ember-Router: dynamically create state from a recursive path

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I need a way for ember router to route to a recursive path.

```
For Example:
/:module
/:module/:submodule
/:module/:submodule/:submodule
/:module/:submodule/:submodule/...
```

Can this be done with Embers router, and if so, how?

I've been looking for examples, tearing apart the source, and I've pretty much come to the conclusion, it's not possible.

In a previous question, someone had pointed me to a way to get the url manually and split it, but I'm stuck at creating the state for the router to resolve to.

As of now, in my project, I currently just use the Ember.HashLocation to setup my own state manager.

The reason for the need of this, is because the module definitions are stored in a database, and at any given point a submodule of a submodule, recursively, could be added. So I'm trying to make the Application Engine handle the change.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to build an app with a similar scenario.

Comment: Any success with this?

Comment: Honestly, no. I haven't played with this in over a year. I've since moved on from ember. I'd check out their website, there was supposedly a solution for it coming.

Oddly enough, this is a common issue in Rails like implementations... Grails is giving me the same issue.

Comment: Set the router path to 'someroute/:module' and set array of submodules in queryParameter. Check this https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/query-params/

Answer (score 1):

Do your submodules in the database not have unique IDs? It seems to me that rather than representing your hierarchy in the path, you should just go straight to the appropriate module or submodule. Of course the hierarchy is still in your data model, but it shouldn't *have* to be represented in your routing scheme. Just use:

```
/module/:moduleId
/submodule/:submoduleId
```

And don't encode the hierarchy in the routes. I understand it might be natural to do so, but there's probably not a technical reason to.

If your submodules *don't* have unique ids, it's maybe a little tougher...you could build a unique ID by concatenating the ancestor ids together (say, with underscores), which is similar to splitting the URL, but a little cleaner probably. I will say that Ember/Ember Data doesn't seem to be too easy to use with entities with composite keys--if everything has a simple numeric key everything becomes easier (anyone want to argue with me on this, please explain to me how!).

Comment: It needs to be able to be recursive with any number of submodules. So, unfortunately, no this is not what I need.

Though, I do see what you are saying, but I need to be able to create state that matches a url friendly name, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

DO you mean like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  match('/posts').to('blogPosts');
  match('/posts/:blog_post_id').to('showBlogPost');
});
```

Comment: It needs to be recursive without a hard set number of parameters.